# How long till I can use the property of a magic item again?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I was reading about how you can "activate" the animated shield and it will float for a minute or so.

My question is: how long till I can use this item's property again? And is it the same for every other magic item?

Comment: I down-voted this question because it's poorly researched. Each magic item's description does a fairly good job of clearly delineating when and how often its effects may be used.

Comment: Folks, the querent prefers his spelling. Don't edit it out due to your own cultural biases.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the specific case of the animated shield, you can reuse it as soon as you spend a bonus action to reuse it (*DMG*, p. 151). In general, each magic item has its own rules for frequency of use, and there is no universal rule.